# Filtering for top goal scorer in each team

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a graph of football (soccer) data. I want to create a table of the most prolific goal scorer for each team.

I am able to generate a table (using the query below) listing all the players who have scored goals, the number of goals each player has scored and the team they play for. I have ordered the table by team, and number of goals scored in descending order. I am only interested in the top goal scorer  for each team but am stuck on how to filter out all the other players.

```
    MATCH (e:Event)-[:INVOLVING]->(p:Player)-[:PLAYED_FOR]->(t:Team)
    WHERE e.eventType = 'GOAL'
    RETURN t.teamName AS teamName, p.name AS playerName, COUNT(DISTINCT(e)) AS goalCount
    ORDER BY teamName, goalCount DESC
```

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you explain why you used `DISTINCT`? I left it out of my answer, as it requires more computation but seemed unnecessary.

Comment: Without DISTINCT I was getting a count of several hundred goals for each player. When I used DISTINCT the query would return the correct number of goals. I didn't think too much of it as I am just learning an was delight that it worked. How ever after your comment I went back and looked at the query and realised the problem.

Comment: Some of the players transfer teams during the season. To overcome this the :PLAYED_FOR relationship exists for every match the player played in for that particular team. As a result when I left out DISTINCT I would get (the number of time that player had played for that team ) X (the number of goals that player had scored) which is why I was getting such large numbers. Have you any tips on how I can improve/avoid this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may work for you:

```
MATCH (e:Event)-[:INVOLVING]->(p:Player)-[:PLAYED_FOR]->(t:Team)
WHERE e.eventType = 'GOAL'
WITH t.teamName AS teamName, p.name AS playerName, COUNT(e) AS goalCount
ORDER BY teamName, goalCount DESC
RETURN teamName, COLLECT({player: playerName, goalCount: goalCount})[0] AS top
```